# Bootstrap 4 cols not working in Angular Component

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

If I have an angular component "sidebar" with bootstrap col inside it the grid breaks.

My app.component.html

```
<div id="wrapper" style="padding-top: 80px;">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-searchrow></app-searchrow>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
                <div class="col-md-9">Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

my sidebar.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">Sidebar Content</div>
```

but if I use the following it works:

my app.component.html

```
<div id="wrapper" style="padding-top: 80px;">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-searchrow></app-searchrow>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
                    <app-sidebarfilter></app-sidebarfilter>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

my sidebar.component.html

```
<p>sidebar content</p>
```

What is going on, in many instances it would be beneficial to have the col in components. But why isn't it working  like I would expect? I don't remember this from he last time I worked with angular a year or two ago.

Using:
bootstrap 4
angular 7.0

Comment: can you make a functional example with the problem?

Comment: please see above

Comment: Please take a look at this : https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/layout/grid-usage/

Answer (score 4):

make the sidebar component to be like this, first level inside a `.row` MUST be `col-SOMETHING`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="wrapper" style="padding-top: 80px;">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-searchrow></app-searchrow>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div app-sidebarfilter class="col-xs-3">sidebar</div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Comment: so you're suggesting changing the component selector to an attribute? That doesn't solve the problem, of wanting to put the col class inside the *.component.html. Strange the requirement for the col class to be immediately after the row class seems to be an issue with bootstrap 4, that wasn't present in 3

Answer (score 3):

you can add the class to your component tag, e.g.
< app-sidebarfilter class="col-xs-3">

Answer (score 3):

You can use display: contents

```
<app-sidebarfilter style="display: contents;">
```